# Clean solution for optional yet required variables

Tags: design-patterns, uml

Is there some kind of design pattern for the following situation?

[image: Current design]

Requirements:

- `lat` and `lon` are always required.
- `place` and/or `name` are optional (can be null).
- When the optional variables are null, `getPlace()` and `getName()` should return the `lat` and `lon` as string.

The current situation seems kinda "dirty" to me, so i was wondering if there is "clean" solution. I could not find the answer myself.

Comment: Why do the check, every time, in the getters, rather than doing it once, in the constructor(s)? Why don't you post code instead of drawings?

Comment: Doing it once can do the trick, maybe I'm over thinking it. No code because I'm creating a design.

Comment: Then you shouldn't think about a method doing null checks. You should establish the contract of each method, i.e. write their javadoc. But most of the time, the design emerges from the code, and not vice-versa. Start coding, use the classes you've coded, see if it feels intuitive and natural, refactor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the optional from the required variables and use
polymorphism to avoid null-checks in `getName()` and `getPlace()`.
Maybe something like the following:

[image]

Comment: This looks very nice. However, what about a situation where both the place and name are defined? Like a `LocationWithNameAndPlace` class. Then this class should have both variables and methods, but this means  redundancy of code if I'm correct

Comment: @Gilian You could derive `LocationWithNameAndPlace` from `LocationWithName` and `LocationWithPlace`, there will be no redundancy. What is the programming language used to implement it?

Comment: The language is Java.

Answer (score 3):

The pattern you need to apply is called constraint. Simply attach two `<<invariant>>` constraints to your class telling

```
{lat and lon are always required}
```

and

```
{place and/or name are optional (can be null)}
```

The text

> When the optional variables are null, getPlace() and getName() should return the lat and lon as string.

is part of the behavioral description of the class.

As a side note: "should" means you can implement if you are a nice guy, but if you ignore it you can't be beaten. Use "shall".

Comment: I don't think it answers the question. If I understand it correctly, the question is "how to improve the current design?" and not "how to model the current design in UML".

Comment: @sergej He asks "Is there some kind of design pattern for the following situation?" and this is the pattern to use (the question is tagged UML)

Answer (score 2):

According to comment of [JP Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet) you can implement the `Location` as immutable object and provide two factory methods:

```
class Location
{
    private readonly double lat;
    private readonly double lon;
    private readonly string place;
    private readonly string name;

    // Hide the constructor and only allow creation using the factory methods
    // Alternative: Only provide factory method with lat and lon parameters and make this constructor public
    private Location(double lat, double lon, string place, string name)
    {
        this.lat = lat;
        this.lon = lon;
        this.place = place;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Factory methods
    public static Location Create(double lat, double lon)
    {
        return new Location(lat, lon, lat.ToString(), lon.ToString());
    }

    public static Location Create(double lat, double lon, string place, string name)
    {
        return new Location(lat, lon, place, name);
    }

    public double getLat()
    {
        return this.lat;
    }

    public double getLon()
    {
        return this.lon;
    }

    public string getPlace()
    {
        return this.place;
    }

    public string getName()
    {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

Now it's up to the user what strategy is used to create an instance of the `Location` class.

**Edit:** Code provided only to show the idea of the two (implicit) strategies.

Answer (score 1):

By default, each UML property has a multiplicity of 1. Section 9.5.4 of the UML 2.5 specification says:

> *<multiplicity-range>* is the multiplicity range of the Property. If this term is omitted, it implies a multiplicity of 1 (exactly one).

This means that, in your diagram, all properties (lat, lon, place, name) are mandatory. To indicate that a property is optional, you can append the multiplicity range `[0..1]` after the property type.

[image: class Location]

The behavior of the getPlace and getName methods is generally not included in a class diagram. A class diagram is primarily meant to specify structure, not behavior. You may include a note, as you did, but personally, I would describe this kind of behavior in plain text, not in any diagram. Most UML tools allow you to write plain text descriptions for every operation and generate a document containing all these descriptions. But this is just one way to do it. You could also use Word or a Wiki.